# startActivityForResult with three activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have three activities, let's just call them Activity A, Activity B and Activity C

At first I'm at the Activity A and I'm starting a QR scanner (Activity B) with startActivityForResult like this:

```
Intent i;
i = new Intent(this, QrActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Once the Activity B opens, this is the code for handling result and returning to previous activity:

```
 public void handleDecode(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) 
{

    if (rawResult != null) {
        String textResult = rawResult.getText();

        if (textResult != null) {
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", textResult);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
            finish();       
        }
//rest of the code
```

Now this works completely fine, once the Activity A is opened again everything works as it should. It goes like this: A --> B --> A

The problem appears when I try to go like this: A --> C --> B --> A

The user has two options, either to start the Activity B (qr scanner) from Activity A or from Activity C. I always want to handle Activity B result with Activity A even if the user accessed Activity B from Activity C.

Once I open the Activity B (qr scanner) from activity C, this is how I tried to solve it:

I called finish() on Activity C when Activity B is called:

```
Intent in;
in = new Intent(this, QrActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(in, 1);
finish();
```

And in Activity B, instead of

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
```

I'm setting intent as:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(QrActivity.this, CheckpointsActivity.class);
```

And after it goes back to activity A nothing happens, like the Activity B was never even opened, it doesn't seem to get the result when Activity B is started from Activity C.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated! I know this is all very confusing but I can add any more detail if you want.

Comment: Check your manifest. Is `noHistory` (or such name) enabled on your Activities?

Comment: @hichris123 no, there's nothing like noHistory or anything like it enabled for activities

Comment: I assume in the second scenario that `onCreate()` of `ActivityA` is being called?

Comment: @codeMagic the onActivityResult should be called but it isn't, and onCreate isn't being called either so I'm assuming the onResume is called, but isn't the onActivityResult supposed to be called with onResume? It just makes no sense to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how `startActivityForResult()` is meant to work. You would be better off saving the data in `SharedPreferences` or somewhere else.

You also could probably use `startActivityForResult()` to start `ActivityC` from A then do the same to start B from C (don't finish C yet), passing back the result you want to pass to A. So it would be something like

A --> C --> B (finish) --> C (finish) --> A

using `startActivityForResult()` to start C and B and returning a result with `setResult()` to the `onActivityResult()` of both C and A