# back to previous activity with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activity, and when I press enter on first activity, it will open second activity, it contains a `ListView` and when I choose an item from `ListView`, it will get its value and bring back to first activity

this is what I've tried;

**on second activity**

```
listPerasat.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            NamaPrst = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtListNamaPrst)).getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("NAMA_PERASAT", NamaPrst);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

on first activity

```
edtText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("NAMA_PERASAT")); // inside onCreate
```

or

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    edtText.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("NAMA_PERASAT"));
}
```

but nothing happen. how can I get intent and back to previous activity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to call `startActivityForResult()` for this. So in your first `Activity` something like

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, SOME_REQUEST_CODE); // you give SomeRequesSOME_REQUEST_CODE an int value
```

then in your `onItemClick()` you need to call `setResult()` and send back the `Intent`. This will call `onActivityResult()` in your first `Activity`

```
listPerasat.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        NamaPrst = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtListNamaPrst)).getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("NAMA_PERASAT", NamaPrst);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
    }
});
}
```

In `onActivityResult()` in your first `Activity`, don't call `getIntent()`. This will try to use the `Intent` that originally started your first `Activity`. Instead, use the `Intent` you passed back

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    edtText.setText(data.getStringExtra("NAMA_PERASAT"));
}
```

[See this answer for another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387659/startactivityforresult-with-three-activities/20404668#20404668)

Comment: Nice, it works, but what is `SOME_REQUEST_CODE` for? I tried with 1 it got an error, then I tried with 0, and everything works fine

Comment: You can use 0 or you can create your own `constant int` to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, ViewMessageDialog.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("NAMA_PERASAT", message);
ctx.startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to start an activity so right before

```
finish();
```

i.e.

```
startActivity(intent);
// or to start with a back result
// startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE, EXTRA_BUNDLE);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

call the second activity for result. it will return your selected data on OnAcitiviyResult. 
just like below:

[link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Answer (score 0):

In `second activity` edit your code like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("NAMA_PERASAT", NamaPrst);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
```

then in `first activity's` onActivityResult(), first check if the result was "OK" i.e. something was selected.

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        edtText.setText(data.getStringExtra("NAMA_PERASAT"));
      }
    }
```

If after opening second activity you didn't selected anything and pressed `back button` then you will get errors since nothing was passed from `second activity`. So first check that if the `setResult(RESULT_OK, i);` was executed i.e. `extras` were added and we manually set that everything is `OK` now.