# Android - set text after changing activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities: MainActivity and SecondActicity.
On MainActivity I click on a button and go to SecondActicity:

```
public void GoToSeconActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);;
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

On secondActivity I click on a button and then I go back to MainActivity and also send extras:

```
public void goBackToMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("myVar", myVar);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

on MainActivity's onCreate I want to show **myVar** in an EditText

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
        .commit();
    }

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
        EditText myVarEdittext1 =   (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.myVarEditText);
        string str = extras.getString("myVar");
        myVarEdittext1.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.
I try to add `myVarEdittext1.postInvalidate();` after setText and it didn't help.
I also tried to put this code in

```
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
    public void run() {
        View myView = ....
        //...
        myVarEdittext1.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
 });
```

and it didn't help too...

What else can I do? There is no exception - but the editText remains empty.

Comment: Before setting `myVar` into `EditText` please `Toast` the value of `myVar` to check if there is any value for `myVar`

Comment: What is Toast? Anyway I also tried to put "blabla" in setText(), without being depended on extras, and it didn't work.

Comment: Put this `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` instead of `myVarEdittext1.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);` and check if anything is displayed..

Comment: @codeMagic - still not working, editText stays empty...

Comment: Did you try adding the toast????This is just for debugging..Please do it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity` and extract `myVar` from there:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    string str = data.getString("myVar");
}
```

And you also need to change call from `startActivity` to `startActivityForResult`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code that gets the `Intent` data and sets the text on your `EditText`.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
        EditText myVarEdittext1 =   (EditText)myView.findViewById(R.id.myVarEditText);
        string str = extras.getString("myVar");
        myVarEdittext1.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }
```

You don't seem to be finishing the `Activity` so `onCreate()` is not called but `onResume()` will be called.

You could also use `startActivityForResult()`.

[Here is an example of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558689/back-to-previous-activity-with-intent/20558774#20558774)

[Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

If your Second Activity returns data to your MainActivity then You should have launched the the SecondActivity in the MainActivity Using "startActivityForResult".
Then when u launch the SecondActivity in the app , u have to get back to the MainActivity in a different way.
Data is returned to the MainActivity using a Uri.
That's of Advanced Android Development as a beginner u should not get after these things.
If u want to know more about Sub-Activity which is what i gave u , Just perform some google search and examples of subactivities and returning data from them.