# where is onActivityResult function in android Activity?

Tags: android

I am a beginner of android programming, but I can not find onActivityResult function in my activity class. there are only onCreate, onCreateOptionsMenu,and onOptionsItemsSelected functions in my activity file.
So my question is where I can find onActivityResult function. thank you guys.

Comment: You have to add it.  Um, if you really need to ask this question I'm not sure if you really understand what a function is, how they work, and how inheritance works.  You really should learn standard Java programming before diving into Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by adding it

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // your code
}
```

It won't be added automagically because you don't need it unless you start the next `Activity` with `startActivityForResult()`. Then it is called by calling `setResult()` in the `Activity` started with `startActivtyForResult()`.

[See the docs for more information](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[This answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558689/back-to-previous-activity-with-intent/20558774#20558774) should also give you a good idea of how and why to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override it! 
If you're using android studio...

> Right click-generate-override- and select onActivityResult

In eclipse, you need to code it manually

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see it there, simply add it to your class.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, you can create it automatically without typing the code with shortcut `Ctrl+O` to generate any override method. That shortcut will bring you a pop up window where you can search the override method you need.